# Using a stored procedure in BIRT with multiple outputs

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, report, birt

So I'm running into a problem with my stored procedure not returning the correct columns from my stored procedure in BIRT. I have 9 different outputs in my stored procedure.

For some reason, they are not returning the proper columns when I select different result sets from the settings. Even though when I look at the data in the preview results tab returning the correct columns and data.

How can I selectively choose the different output results and display the correct columns on my report?

Thank you

Comment: If you run the procedure not using BIRT does it do what it's supposed to do?

Comment: Yes it runs when I ran them in SQL developer